# jQuery Knob with SetInterval breaks CSS

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-knob

I came across jQuery Knob the other day and it's perfect for a project I'm working on. Awesome work Anthony:

The object is to create a knob(s) and display on a page using data collected from an array of objects storing the required data.

What I need to achieve is looping through either a $.each(data, function... loop or a for loop, with a pause between each loop.

Something like this:

```
 (function($) {

  $.each(data, function(i, item) {
    buildPage(item);
    // Use a delay here of x number of seconds before looping again
  }

 )(jQuery);
```

I tried setIntervals and setTimeout, I did get it working at one stage, however all the css for the jquery-knob.js file wouldn't load, which is the important part as it draws the knobs.

I'm still pretty green when it comes to development so any examples w/ explanations would really help. Thanks.

In the end I achieved the desired effect with the code below, parsing a variable in to a page refresh, but this is only a work around.

```
  var page = getUrlVars('page') || 0;

   // Go time!!!
    (function($) {
console.log('document ready');  

buildPage(data[page]);

if(page == data.length - 1) {
    page = 0;
} else {
    page = parseInt(page) + 1;
}

setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = 'index.html?page='+page;
}, 5000);
  })(jQuery);
```

Comment: can u provide some jsfiddle example ?